# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string calculate days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate the totaldays in this store procedure, but I keep getting the conversion error:

```
DECLARE @ifIsMarch varchar(6), @addOneDay date, @startDay int,        
@disconnectDay int, @startMonth int, @disconnectMonth int, @startYear   
int, @disconnectYear int, @totaldays int

SELECT @startDay = DAY('2014-02-28') 
SELECT @disconnectDay = DAY('2014-10-31') 
SELECT @startMonth = MONTH('2014-02-28') 
SELECT @disconnectMonth = MONTH('2014-10-31') 
SELECT @startYear = YEAR('2014-02-28') 
SELECT @disconnectYear = YEAR('2014-10-31')

print @startDay
print @disconnectDay
print @startMonth
print @disconnectMonth
print @startYear
print @disconnectYear

SELECT @addOneDay = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, '2014-02-28'))
SELECT @ifIsMarch = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @addOneDay, 110), 5)

print @addOneDay
Print @ifIsMarch

select @totaldays = 
CASE 
  WHEN @ifIsMarch = '03-01'  THEN
  CASE
    WHEN @DisconnectDate = '31' THEN (360*(@disconnectYear - @startYear)) + (30*(@disconnectMonth - @startMonth))
    ELSE (360*(@disconnectYear - @startYear)) + (30*(@disconnectMonth - @startMonth)) + (@disconnectDay - 30)
  END
END

print @totaldays
```

Comment: You haven't declared the `@DisconnectDate` variable

Comment: And the only thing that you want to do is to get the number of days between 2 dates?, then you obviously should use `DATEDIFF` as the current answer says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i get conversion error with datetime, i usually change positions of month number with day number and it begins to work

to get difference between two dates i would suggest to use DATEDIFF

```
declare @startDate datetime = '20140228'
declare @disconnectDate datetime = '20141031'
SELECT datediff(day, @startDate, @disconnectdate)
```

if you have dates with -

```
declare @startDate datetime = convert(datetime, '2014-02-28', 21)
declare @disconnectDate datetime = convert(datetime, '2014-10-31', 21)
SELECT datediff(day, @startDate, @disconnectdate)
```

Comment: remove "-" works!  But how do I convert '2014-02-08' to '20140228' as the date is pulled from the table?

Comment: @angelcake, try this: select convert(datetime,'2014-02-28', 21) -- 21 is a  specific format yyyy-mm-dd; it will just convert string to datetime

Comment: I need to change '2014-02-08' to  '20140228' as you suggested earlier.  21 is yyyy-mm-dd, not yyyymmdd